# Remove "Texture has been resized" console logs in three.js

Tags: three.js

I see warnings like the following in the console for my threejs project.

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (613x345) to (512x256).
```

Researching around, it looks like its not something to be concerned about. But I would like to remove these logs to keep the console clean. How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 18):

Setting

```
texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
```

will turn off mipmapping and the need for resizing to a power-of-two.

Or, manually resize your textures to a power-of-two before you use them.

three.js r.102

Comment: BTW: Using WebGL 2 also avoids this message since it's not necessary anymore to distinct between both types of textures. Mipmapping also works with NPOT textures.

Answer (score 2):

If you use loader(such `FBXLoader`,`ObjectLoader`),you can resize image before WebGLTextures do this.Here is my solution:

```js
  function resizeImage(image) {
    const scale = 1
    const width = THREE.Math.floorPowerOfTwo(scale * image.width)
    const height = THREE.Math.floorPowerOfTwo(scale * image.height)
    if (width === image.width && height === image.height) {
      return image
    }
    if ((typeof HTMLImageElement !== 'undefined' && image instanceof HTMLImageElement) ||
        (typeof HTMLCanvasElement !== 'undefined' && image instanceof HTMLCanvasElement) ||
        (typeof ImageBitmap !== 'undefined' && image instanceof ImageBitmap)) {
      document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas')

      const canvas = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas')

      canvas.width = width
      canvas.height = height

      const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height)
      return canvas
    } else {
      return image
    }
  }

  function resizeAllImages(obj) {
    // console.log('resizeAllImages')
    obj.traverse(o => {
      if (o.material) {
        if (o.material.map && o.material.map.image) {
          o.material.map.image = this.resizeImage(o.material.map.image)
        } else if (o.material.length > 1) {
          o.material.forEach(m => {
            if (m.map && m.map.image) {
              m.map.image = this.resizeImage(m.map.image)
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

resize image after load model and parse texure image,and before WebGLTextures.

```js
function onLoad(obj) {
  // ...
      // FXB loader async loading texture image.
      setTimeout(() => {
        resizeAllImages(scene)
      }, 1)
  //...
}

//loader.load(url,onLoad)
```

relative code in `renderers\webgl\WebGLTextures.js`

```js
    function resizeImage( image, needsPowerOfTwo, needsNewCanvas, maxSize ) {

        var scale = 1;

        // handle case if texture exceeds max size

        if ( image.width > maxSize || image.height > maxSize ) {

            scale = maxSize / Math.max( image.width, image.height );

        }

        // only perform resize if necessary

        if ( scale < 1 || needsPowerOfTwo === true ) {

            // only perform resize for certain image types

            if ( ( typeof HTMLImageElement !== 'undefined' && image instanceof HTMLImageElement ) ||
                ( typeof HTMLCanvasElement !== 'undefined' && image instanceof HTMLCanvasElement ) ||
                ( typeof ImageBitmap !== 'undefined' && image instanceof ImageBitmap ) ) {

                var floor = needsPowerOfTwo ? _Math.floorPowerOfTwo : Math.floor;

                var width = floor( scale * image.width );
                var height = floor( scale * image.height );

                if ( _canvas === undefined ) _canvas = createCanvas( width, height );

                // cube textures can't reuse the same canvas

                var canvas = needsNewCanvas ? createCanvas( width, height ) : _canvas;

                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;

                var context = canvas.getContext( '2d' );
                context.drawImage( image, 0, 0, width, height );

                console.warn( 'THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture has been resized from (' + image.width + 'x' + image.height + ') to (' + width + 'x' + height + ').' );

                return canvas;

            } else {

                if ( 'data' in image ) {

                    console.warn( 'THREE.WebGLRenderer: Image in DataTexture is too big (' + image.width + 'x' + image.height + ').' );

                }

                return image;

            }

        }

        return image;

    }

    function textureNeedsPowerOfTwo( texture ) {

        if ( isWebGL2 ) return false;

        return ( texture.wrapS !== ClampToEdgeWrapping || texture.wrapT !== ClampToEdgeWrapping ) ||
            ( texture.minFilter !== NearestFilter && texture.minFilter !== LinearFilter );

    }
```

three.js r.109